# Connect QML signal of arbitrary placed .qml-file to Qt slot

Tags: qt, qml, qurl

I am trying to connect `QML` signal to `Qt` slot. I have read that [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html/) and here is code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qDebug()<<QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml");
    QQuickView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));//I should replace that line
    QObject *item = view.rootObject();

    MyClass myClass;
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
```

}

It works fine, but the problem is that `main.qml` should be in the folder where `.exe` file is. So, every time I modify `main.qml` I should copy it to another foder. File path to `main.qml` is: "C:\Qt\projects\ConnectionsQT\main.qml". I have tried to replace line by

```
QQuickView view(QUrl("‪C:\Qt\projects\ConnectionsQT\main.qml");
```

and by

```
QQuickView view(QUrl("‪C:\\Qt\\projects\\ConnectionsQT\\main.qml");
```

but in that cases the program cannot find the `main.qml` file. What should I do?

Comment: The title of this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem you've encountered.  At any rate, the issue appears to be that you stopped using `QUrl::fromLocalFile()`.  URLs cannot begin with c:\

Answer (score 2):

The good practice is making your qml file part of the app executable by putting into .qrc resource file with Qt creator or by hand:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#managing-resource-files-with-the-qt-resource-system

And the you can make use of it with something like:

```
QQuickView view(QUrl("qrc:///res/qml/main.qml"));
```